# Why my iPhone can not connect to the ipv6 network which is shared by my Mac mini?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipv6

I follow with the [apple doc about ipv6](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1)

At there **Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly**, I follow the steps strictly, but in the end my iPhone 5c can not connect to the ipv6 network.

The snapshot is below:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Attention**

The yellow Chinese means: there is no network connection.

Ignore airplane mode, I have tested if close the airplane mode.

Comment: Not a programming related question. There are chance that you'll get fast answer, here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try turning off Wi-Fi e.g. use a cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's instructions suggest turning off Wi-Fi

[image]